# Android app loads but crashes when SeekBar is released.

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Sorry about what is likely a noob question. 
I am working on a simple android app that involves a seekbar.

The app runs, however, when I release the seekBar it causes my app to crash.

Im trying to set a textview when the seekbar is released, but instead of setting the textview, the app crashes.

I believe this is my issue. When I comment it out, I can drag the seekbar with no issues.

```
progressTextView.setText(progressChangedValue) ;
```

XML CODE

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="329dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    android:max="1000"
    android:progress="500" />
```

JAVA

```
SeekBar seeker = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar) ;
        progressTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekBarLabel);




            seeker.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                int progressChangedValue = 0;
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                progressChangedValue = progress;
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                progressTextView.setText(progressChangedValue) ;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Crash you say ? Please post your stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an integer to [setText(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)), which is a resource id and does not exist in your case, so try changing it to a `String` or other types instead:

```
progressTextView.setText(String.valueOf(progressChangedValue));
```

Comment: Thanks! That took care of it. Makes sense. The stack trace was giving me this:  "Invalid ID 0x00000200." and then a bunch of other stuff.